# DataGridView mixed its content based on xml C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I have a dataGridView which uses an xml as data saving source(for data and cell style), when I use `dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column", column1");` and I close the program and re-open it, all the preloaded data gets disordered. Does someone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having helped you with the XML [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304556/save-and-load-datagridview-content-and-style-in-c-sharp), I replicated your issue by calling `this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column", "column1");` after calling the method to load the saved data into the DataGridView.

Your issue is that once this new column gets saved, the next time you run the program it reads from the xml and loads the data cell by cell into your existing DataGridView cells.  But if `this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column", "column1");` is called *after* loading the dgv from xml, then the cells in the added column don't exist in time to get populated.

You need to make this call *before* loading the xml into the dgv.