# Saving column properties to XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview

So I succeeded in using a XML file to save and load data from my datagridview. But when I load the file I lose the column properties in my datagridview since I am using .columns.clear. Does anybody know how I can retain my column properties/save the properties to the XML file? Also is it possible to save additional textbox and datagridview data in the same XML file?  my code is below:

```vb
Public Class Dimensioneringsapp
'datasets
Dim DataRekenTab As DataSet

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 

    'save dataset
    DataRekenTab = CreateDataset(Rekenwaardes)
    Rekenwaardes.DataSource = DataRekenTab.Tables("TestSave")

End Sub

 'load
Private Sub OpenProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenProjectToolStripMenuItem.Click
    LoadFromXMLfile("C:\SaveTest.xml")
End Sub

'save
Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
    AddDataSet(DataRekenTab, Rekenwaardes)
    SaveToXMLFile("C:\SaveTest.xml", DataRekenTab)
End Sub

Private Function CreateDataset(g As DataGridView) As DataSet
    Dim dataset1 As New DataSet("SaveTest")
    Dim table1 As New DataTable("SaveTest")

    'counter
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do While i < g.ColumnCount
        table1.Columns.Add(g.Columns(i).HeaderText)

        i = i + 1
    Loop

    dataset1.Tables.Add(table1)

    Return dataset1
End Function

Private Sub AddDataSet(d As DataSet, g As DataGridView)

    'counter voor doorlopen tabel
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While i < g.RowCount
        d.Tables("SaveTest").Rows.Add(g(0, i).Value, g(1, i).Value, g(2, i).Value, g(3, i).Value, g(4, i).Value, g(5, i).Value)
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub SaveToXMLFile(filename As String, d As DataSet)
    Dim ser As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(DataSet))
    Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(filename)
    ser.Serialize(writer, d)
    writer.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadFromXMLfile(filename As String)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        Dim xmlSerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(DataRekenTab.GetType)
        Dim readStream As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)

        Rekenwaardes.Columns.Clear()

        DataRekenTab = CType(xmlSerializer.Deserialize(readStream), DataSet)
        readStream.Close()
        Rekenwaardes.DataSource = DataRekenTab.Tables("SaveTest")
    Else
        MsgBox("file not found! add data and press save button first.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "")
    End If
End Sub

End class
```

new code:

```
Private Sub SaveToXMLFile(filename As String, d As DataSet)
    d.WriteXml(filename, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
    Dim ser As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(DataSet))
    Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(filename)
    ser.Serialize(writer, d)
    writer.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub LoadFromXMLfile(filename As String)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        Dim xmlSerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(DataRekenTab.GetType)
        Dim readStream As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)

        Rekenwaardes.Columns.Clear()

        DataRekenTab = CType(xmlSerializer.Deserialize(readStream), DataSet)
        readStream.Close()
        DataRekenTab.ReadXml(filename, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema)
        Rekenwaardes.DataSource = DataRekenTab.Tables("SaveTest")
    Else
        MsgBox("file not found! add data and press save button first.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: By "column properties" do you mean the schema of the DataTable the grid is bound to or do you mean the DGV column properties (things like width, column order, etc.)?

Comment: I mean the DGV properties, like column width and settings for example the not sortable setting

Comment: Can you serialize the DGV's Columns property to your filestream?

Comment: It's in C#, but the concepts should work for you. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28328879/3773066) I show how to save such settings as the `ForeColor` and `BackColor` by creating a class for those settings and serializing it the same as other data.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
d.WriteXml(filename, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
```

so that the schema will be included in the XML file. And to load the data together with the schema

```
d.ReadXml(filename, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema)
```

Comment: This saves and restores the DataSet.

Comment: @Fyer-Zero In your SaveToXmlFile and LoadFromXmlFile subs

Comment: so I put them in my save and load and my dgv properties are not saved. I put my current code in the question.

Comment: Sorry I thought you said you wanted to save the data table schema. In this case, I think the link that @OhBeWise posted will suit you. Just convert it to VB .Net